# Access DataBase Query

Tags: ms-access

hey, my question is that i want to display the names whose payment type is empty.. what should i add after a where clause ?? please help.. and there is also another query that i want to display the names of those which starts with alphabet A.. please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First answer:

WHERE PaymentType IS NULL

Second answer:

WHERE NAME LIKE 'A*'